# Citroen Jumper start issue - PLEASE HELP

Tags: starting, car, citroen

I have a Citroen Jumper (or Relay) 2.2 Hdi 2006
When I start the car the first start is working fine. After that I turn of and start again the starter motor wroking but cant start the car.
If I wait 1-2h and try again. The first start is working fine again... 
Error code list is empty...
What is root cause of this issue?
I have no idea.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! On the second start, what exactly is the engine doing? Do you hear the engine spinning (not just the starter spinning)? If so, are there any signs of life (sputtering or acting like it wants to start, but just not doing it) or does it just spin without anything?